# How to add a caption below a slider?

Tags: javascript, html, css, slider, fade

I was implementing this css3 slider with no jquery at all. How can I add captions for each slide below the slider?

I was working on this: 
https://codepen.io/davidhc/pen/nLpJk

```
<div class='slider'>
  <div class='slide1'></div>
  <div class='slide2'></div>
  <div class='slide3'></div>
</div>
```

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Nest your captions within each child element (`class*="slide"`) of `.slider`

Comment: What do you mean by "caption"?

Answer (score 2):

Please check this. I have added caption inside slide div and give this css for caption:

```
.slider p {
 left: 0;
 position: absolute;
 right: 0;
 text-align: center;
 top: 100%;
}
```

```css
.slider {
  max-width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 20px auto;
  position: relative;
}
.slide1,.slide2,.slide3,.slide4,.slide5 {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.slide1 {
  background: url(http://media.dunkedcdn.com/assets/prod/40946/580x0-9_cropped_1371566801_p17tbs0rrjqdt1u4dnk94fe4b63.jpg)no-repeat center;
  background-size: cover;
  animation:fade 8s infinite;
  -webkit-animation:fade 8s infinite;
} 
.slide2 {
  background: url(http://media.dunkedcdn.com/assets/prod/40946/580x0-9_cropped_1371565525_p17tbqpu0d69c21hetd77dh483.jpeg)no-repeat center;
  background-size: cover;
  animation:fade2 8s infinite;
  -webkit-animation:fade2 8s infinite;
}
.slide3 {
  background: url(http://media.dunkedcdn.com/assets/prod/40946/580x0-9_cropped_1371564896_p17tbq6n86jdo3ishhta3fv1i3.jpg)no-repeat center;
  background-size: cover;
  animation:fade3 8s infinite;
  -webkit-animation:fade3 8s infinite;
}
@keyframes fade
{
  0%   {opacity:1}
  33.333% { opacity: 0}
  66.666% { opacity: 0}
  100% { opacity: 1}
}
@keyframes fade2
{
  0%   {opacity:0}
  33.333% { opacity: 1}
  66.666% { opacity: 0 }
  100% { opacity: 0}
}
@keyframes fade3
{
  0%   {opacity:0}
  33.333% { opacity: 0}
  66.666% { opacity: 1}
  100% { opacity: 0}
}
.slider p {
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  text-align: center;
  top: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class='slider'>
  <div class='slide1'><p>slide1</p></div>
  <div class='slide2'><p>slide2</p></div>
  <div class='slide3'><p>slide3</p></div>
</div>
```

Comment: i think, he want to make this only with css @johnwhitson

Comment: Please explain in your answer, what did you change/updated ?

Comment: @ÁlvaroTouzón but this *is* a css only solution as the OP asked.

Comment: i think, he wants to use only css, like usin :pre or :before and content

Comment: @ÁlvaroTouzón What is `:pre`?

Comment: is a  css property that add to your element a css content before your html content https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_pre.asp @guest271314

Comment: @ÁlvaroTouzón `<pre>` is an HTML element

Comment: yes but it is added only with css not usin html @guest271314

Comment: @ÁlvaroTouzón _"i think, he wants to use only css, like usin :pre or :before and content"_ CSS does not have a defined `:pre` pseudo element or pseudo class. _"is a css property that add to your element a css content before your html content"_ `<pre>` HTML tag is not a CSS property. _"yes but it is added only with css not usin html"_ That is not correct

Comment: @johnwhitson most welcome..:) If answer is useful , accept it.

Answer (score 0):

here is the html and it works with your code but you have to style it by css

```
<div class='slider'>
  <div class='slide1'><div class="carl-caption">
     <h3>burger lover</h3>
     <p>Eat it pal</p>
  </div></div>
  <div class='slide2'><div class="carl-caption">
     <h3>dubai</h3>
     <p>dubai is wild</p>
  </div></div>
  <div class='slide3'><div class="carl-caption">
     <h3>gray land</h3>
     <p>imaginary land</p>
  </div></div>
</div>
```

for css caption try this

```
.slide1:after{content:"My name is lover";
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      right: 0;}
```

Answer (score 0):

I Think this is what u want.

```css
    .slider {
  max-width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 20px auto;
  position: relative;
}
.slide1,
.slide2,
.slide3,
.slide4,
.slide5 {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.slide1 {
  background: url(http://media.dunkedcdn.com/assets/prod/40946/580x0-9_cropped_1371566801_p17tbs0rrjqdt1u4dnk94fe4b63.jpg)no-repeat center;
  background-size: cover;
  animation: fade 8s infinite;
  -webkit-animation: fade 8s infinite;
}

.slide2 {
  background: url(http://media.dunkedcdn.com/assets/prod/40946/580x0-9_cropped_1371565525_p17tbqpu0d69c21hetd77dh483.jpeg)no-repeat center;
  background-size: cover;
  animation: fade2 8s infinite;
  -webkit-animation: fade2 8s infinite;
}
.slide3 {
  background: url(http://media.dunkedcdn.com/assets/prod/40946/580x0-9_cropped_1371564896_p17tbq6n86jdo3ishhta3fv1i3.jpg)no-repeat center;
  background-size: cover;
  animation: fade3 8s infinite;
  -webkit-animation: fade3 8s infinite;
}
@keyframes fade {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  33.333% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  66.666% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
@keyframes fade2 {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  33.333% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  66.666% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
@keyframes fade3 {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  33.333% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  66.666% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
.slider p {
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  text-align: center;
  top: 100%;
}

.slide1:after {
    position: absolute;
    content: "Slide one";
    bottom: -25px;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}
.slide2:after {
    position: absolute;
    content: "Slide Two";
    bottom: -25px;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}
.slide3:after {
    position: absolute;
    content: "Slide Three";
    bottom: -25px;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
    <div class='slider'>
  <div class='slide1'></div>
  <div class='slide2'></div>
  <div class='slide3'></div>
</div>
```

Comment: If you are happy with my code then give me +1. For that you just need to click on up arrow.